# Use geocoding ext for own extension?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have a question.

I have a custom address extension with a mapAction.
Now I would like to create a google map with marker of all addresses.

How can I output all addresses in latlng with the extension "geocoding"?
I do not know how I use this? I would need latlng in fluid.

If this is not so easy, I will have to insert the latlng over the backend itself.

Thank you.

I use TYPO3 8.7.x

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jokumer/TYPO3-map, you can copy and configure all you need, to enable geocoding in your address table.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look at it.

Comment: @jokumer Thank you very much. Worked great.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to output exactly? I think, the extension `geocoding` provides you an API to get LatLng and range search powered by Google Maps. But I see no hints that there is a map output.

I would suggest to use an extension which provides this e.g. `maps2`:
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/maps2/

Comment: That's right! I'll create the map via JS. I need the addresses in LatLng.